# Can we use contour integration to compute the Fourier transform of Gaussian?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}.$ It is known that the Fourier transform of Gaussian is a Gaussian.

> **My question**: Can we use complex analysis (contour integration etc..)  to compute
>
> $$\hat{f}(\xi)= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x^2} e^{ix\xi} dx \ (\xi \in \mathbb R)$$

**Motivation**: My motivation comes from trying to justify:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\left(\frac{1}{t^2}+i\frac{1}{2t}\right)x^2}e^{-i2\pi x\xi} dx & = &  \int_\mathbb{R}  e^{-\frac{\sqrt{4+t^2}}{2t^2}x^2}e^{-i2\pi x \left(e^{-\frac{i}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\xi\right)} dx \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

which came about from an Answer to a previous (now deleted) Question.

Comment: You can but also you do not have to.

Comment: @MariosGretsas: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out the following:
By considering a pie sliced shaped contour in the complex plane along the rays $\varphi = 0$ and $\varphi = -\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$ and a circular arc connecting them, one gets that 


$
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\left(\frac{1}{t^2}+i\frac{1}{2t}\right)x^2}e^{-i2\pi x\xi} dx =  \int_\mathbb{R}  e^{-\frac{\sqrt{4+t^2}}{2t^2}x^2}e^{-i2\pi x \left(e^{-\frac{i}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\xi\right)} dx 
$
? I thought  for only for Gaussian there is a similar argument?

Comment: You can consider also a rectangular contour.. take a look at these notes at page 65...exercise 5.2.2..http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~papadim/complex_analysis_2019/gca_vn_r.pdf do this exercise if you want

Comment: The easiest would be to complete a square inside exponential function, I think.

Comment: Your motivations' link is dead.

Comment: @Cheng:  The OP's earlier Question was deleted by the Community bot, so I've copied the essential content here for context.

Answer (score 3):

We have $\exp[-(x-\frac12 \xi i)^2]=e^{-x^2}e^{\frac14 \xi^2} e^{\xi xi}$.

Consider the countour $\gamma$ connecting points $-R, -R-\frac12 \xi i, R-\frac12 \xi i, R$, where $R>0$. We know that the function
$$
f(z)=\exp(-z^2)
$$
has no singularities inside this countour, so $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$. The integral
\begin{align*}
&\int_{R-\frac 12 \xi i}^R \exp(-z^2) dz \\
&= \int_{-\frac 12 \xi}^0 \exp(-(R+xi)^2) idx\\
&=\exp(-R^2)\int_{-\frac 12 \xi}^0 \exp x^2 \exp (-2Rxi) idx\\
&= 0 \ \text{ as } \ R\to \infty
\end{align*}
Where the integral is bounded.
Similarly,
$$
\int_{-R-\frac 12 \xi i}^{-R} \exp(-z^2) dz\to 0.
$$
As a result,
\begin{align*}
0 &= \int_\gamma f(z)dz\\
0 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp (-x^2) dx - e^{\frac14 \xi^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-x^2}e^{\xi xi}dx
\end{align*}

so,
$$
\mathcal F f(\xi)=\sqrt \pi \exp(-\xi^2/4).
$$